# Swift Package Manager can't add AWS iOS SDK

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, aws-sdk-ios

Looking to add AWS iOS SDK package dependency to an Xcode project. [Documentation](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios-spm) is pretty straightforward. I add a package collection and point it at the URL: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios-spm and then it should work. However, this always yields "Received invalid response at [URL]". I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Using Xcode 15.2. Swift Compiler - Language Version is "unspecified", with options for 5, 4.2, and 4. On a mac.

I am accessing this 'add packages' by going to the .xcodeproj file > Package Dependencies tab > +... The creation of my project generated no `Podfile` or `Packages.swift`. Not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: Just to let you know. Created a new Project and added the dependency without any problem. On MacOS 14.3, using Xcode 15.2, ios project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to add the package in the wrong way. [image: Package add]
Instead of pasting the URL into the search bar in the top right, I instead was trying to paste into the URL input appearing after selecting + -> "Add Package Collection" in the bottom left. Not sure the difference or why the latter didn't work, but that is the answer.